# Facebook advertisements open automatically even when the browser is not currently open

Tags: firefox, browser, viruses, malware

I tried to google the problem for a while and still couldn't find the solution.

My browser periodically open a new tab with a Facebook link even when the browser is not opening. First I guess that's because of Firefox, so I reinstalled Firefox (keeping the profile). Not thing changed.

Now I need your helps.

Also, I'm not sure the link is an ad or not but it's doesn't matter much, it's annoying anyway.

-----------Update-------------

Remove Firefox -> not worked

Dump the profile -> not worked

The problem disappeared by itself. Not sure how..

Comment: Dump the profile!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily check if the problem is in your profile by opening Firefox with a clean profile.

1. Close all Firefox windows.
2. Open terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and execute

   `firefox -ProfileManager`
3. Create a new profile and check if the problem is still present with it.

After this you can try disabling each of your Firefox extensions one by one and seeing if the problem goes away.

Comment: That's a good idea too :) Isn't it easier to use FF's profile manager by starting it with `firefox -ProfileManager`?

Comment: @int_ua Probably (if not used to doing it the renaming way) and I had completely forgot that even existed, go ahead and edit my answer. :)

Comment: That's a heavy edit, but since you are asking, I'll try it.

Comment: I changed Firefox's profile. But the problem is still present. Any other idea?

Comment: @user69234 I do not know, but at least you can now exclude all of your extensions and any profile setting that might have caused this. I'm almost ready to guess that the problem is somewhere else than in Firefox itself (Firefox is probably your default browser, so it could come from any program...).

Answer (score 1):

Chances are it's not the whole system that's affected but only the current user.
You can try finding all files containing the link in question with a command like this:

```
grep -rlF "www.facebook.com/the-link-in-question" $HOME
```

Notice: it will read **all** the files in your home directory so it could take up to several hours if you have TBs of data.

If you don't succeed with it you still can try searching whole system:

```
grep -rlF "www.facebook.com/the-link-in-question" /
```

Please share if you'll find it.

---

P.S. In case you need basics of using the terminal, read this:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal

Comment: I don't know because the link is like a mess and every time it's different. Should I do the search now?

Comment: right now I doubt it will give any results since it will check only non-compressed files. Does it still happen when you are offline? If it's not you can try catching the thing while it gets new links from the network with `sudo lsof -i`